# How do I keep a notification open in firefox?

Tags: javascript, notifications

I have a chat program and I expect people to leave their desk.  When they come back, I would like notifications to still be on the screen.  Chrome can leave up notifications forever, but firefox auto closes.  This isn't great because users aren't going to be staring at their monitors

Firefox seems to auto close notifications.  Is there a nice way to keep it open?

Comment: i don't believe firefox allows that to be over-ridden.

Comment: right.. the workaround i posted below just re-opens it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am currently just re-opening the notification when it closes, and when I explicitly close it(with a click), then I allow it to be actually closed.

```
// This assumes you already checked for permissions and have notifications working

var MyNotify = function(message) {
  this.message = message;
  this.open();
};

MyNotify.prototype.open = function() {
  var self = this;

  // Notification is the native browser method
  self.instance = new Notification(self.message);

  self.instance.addEventListener('close', function(){
    // We force firefox to continually respawn notifications until they explicitly close
    if (!self.shouldClose)
      self.open();
  });

  self.instance.addEventListener('click', function(){
    self.close();
  });

};

MyNotify.prototype.close = function() {
  self.shouldClose = true;
  self.instance.close();
};

new MyNotify('Hello World');
```

Comment: This works but is a UX catastrophe. When the user clicks on the `close button` - the notification reapers.  Its super annoying. Gives one the impression that is being hacked. There should be an easy way to figure out if a notification is closed by the system - or by the user. If is closed by the OS we use this method of re-spawning the notification - but if is closed by the user, it should be captured in another way - maybe `closed_by_user` event or something. `requireInteraction: true` is used for this purpose but it only works in chrome.

Comment: You're right.. this implementation only works on an internal system, where you care a lot about it staying open, but you can teach each sales person the quircks